# ag-grid: Using Drag drop to reorder rows within the grid

Tags: ag-grid

I need to re-order rows within ag-grid by using drag-drop. The drag drop methods are simple enough but when the drop occurs there seems no easy way to switch the rows locations.

I attempted a

```
gridOptions.api.removeItems(selectedNode);
```

to clear the current and then

```
gridOptions.api.insertItemsAtIndex(2, savedNode);
```

but the drop event appeared to re-fire preventing that approach. Plus the insertItems (when ran first) falls over in internal ag-grid looping.

I would rather not re-sort the gridRows manually and then reset the gridRow data which would be somewhat clunky.  This seems a common request on most grids so i assume it can be done but have just missed the relevant documentation. Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K have finally got an Angular 2 method working, though currently I have to switch off sorting and filtering on the grid.

This particular example is relying on row selection being enabled (due to how it is finding some records). Grid dragdrop should be disabled (as that drags the grid visually which sucks) Instead use a processRowPostCreate to set up draggable params at the row level. This sets the dragged option to the row which looks much nicer.

in gridOptions

```
 processRowPostCreate: (params) => {
            this.generateRowEvents(params);
        },
```

which calls

```
private generateRowEvents(params) {
    params.eRow.draggable = true; 
    params.eRow.ondragstart = this.onDrag(event);
    params.eRow.ondragover = this.onDragOver(event);
    params.eRow.ondrop = this.onDrop(event);
}
```

I track the source recrord in the onDrag method

```
                 var targetRowId: any = $event.target.attributes.row.value;
                 this.savedDragSourceData = targetRowId;
```

onDragOver as usual

On drop we have to protect against an infinite loop (ag-grid appears to recall live methods when items are added to the grid hence the ondrop occurs multiple times) and then insert, delete and splice over both the grid and its data source ( I will carry on looking at using the grid to populate the data as opposed to the source data as that would allow source/filter, currently doign that inserts blank rows). An event (in this case) is then emitted to ask the owning component to 'save' the adjusted data.

```
private onDrop($event) {
     if ($event && !this.infiniteLoopCheck) {
         if ($event.dataTransfer) {
             if (this.enableInternalDragDrop) {
                 this.infiniteLoopCheck= true;

                  var draggedRows: any = this.gridRows[this.savedDragSourceData];

                 // get the destination row
                 var targetRowId: any = $event.target.offsetParent.attributes.row.value;

                 // remove  from the current location
                 this.gridOptions.api.removeItems(this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes());

                 // remove from source Data  
                this.gridRows.splice(this.savedDragSourceData, 1);


                 if (draggedRows) {
                     // insert into specified drop location
                     this.gridOptions.api.insertItemsAtIndex(targetRowId, [draggedRows]);

                     // re-add rows to source data..
                     this.gridRows.splice(targetRowId, 0, checkAdd);

                     this.saveRequestEvent.emit(this.gridRows);// shout out that a save is needed                     }
                 this.v= false;
             }
             else {
                 this.onDropEvent.emit($event);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

NOTE we are wrapping the grid in our own class to allow us to write one set of grid methods and not replicate over the application whenever the grid is used.

I will be refining this over the next few days but as a basic this allows the ag-grid in angular 2 to drag drop rows to sort records.

Comment: Hi, Do you have the complete code? I am using angular 2, for me Drop event is not getting fired, any idea what might be wrong ? (I am also trying to reorder in same grid).

Comment: Are you adding the relevant method to the grid html  (dragstart)="setDrag($event)"
                     (dragStopped)="dragStopped($event)"
                     (dragover)="onDragOver($event)"
                     (drop)="onDrop($event)">   Put some logs on those to check they are firing and the problem is not elsewhere. We have written our own wrapper for the grid so it is likely to be unhelpful in its entirety..

Comment: Thanks for your time. That I didn't had in my code; instead I had "generateRowEvents", ( as you mentioned above) - in which I was binding the events. Now I try to add the code you mentioned in HTML; but of no luck :(. Are you using any other package for this (other than ag-grid and ng2-ag-grid) ?

Comment: Got the Fix (Thanks :) ) : Added $event.preventDefault();    to DragOver event                                                        private onDragOver($event) {
        if ($event && this.newDragStarted) {
            $event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

Comment: Glad you have it up and running ;)

Comment: @Relativity could you post your angular2 drag and drop code

Comment: Thanks! This code is really helpful. But I had to change couple of things to get it working

Comment: glad it helped, we have adjusted a few things ourselves due to improvements to the grid and strreamlining as we understand better what is happening in the background.

Comment: NOTE things have changed as the ag-grid develops in version 12.0.0+ we now just set draggable as before but do not link the events (names have changed and the underlying grid does not throw them as before) instead pick up the drag drop events on the grid html.  As a plus when row is set to draggable it correctly shows the ghost of the selected row now as well.

Comment: Default ag-grid 13.0.1 demo of drag drop between grids can be seen in this repo -- https://github.com/matrimsaric/ag-grid-demos

Answer (score 1):

If you don't find a solution within ag-grid then you can do this by adding one more directive("ngDraggable") and integrate it with ag-grid.

Please find the following working plnkr for this.

https://embed.plnkr.co/qLy0EX/

[ngDraggable](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable)

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks for the response, I can try that out if there is no grid based response. That code is angular JS whereas I am using Angular 2 so there may be a compatibility issue there.